# Using WINRAR with batch script

Tags: batch-file, winrar

I am new to scripting, can some please assist me,

I have batch file that

1. Looks at the first 8 characters in the file name, creates and
   moves those files to new folder with first 8 characters as folder
   name.
2. Then looks at folder created in step 1 for next four series
   of character (9,10,11,12)and create and move to another subfolder
   with next 4 characters as folder name.
3. Then looks at folder created in step 2, for extension of every file and create and move
   to a new folder with extension as folder name.

For example, I have files that look like this

```
ABCEFGHI0703xyz.pdf
STUVWXYZ0805xyz.pptx
```

Move to folder

```
ABCEFGHI\0703\PDF
STUVWXYZ\0805\PPTX
```

Keeping in mind first 8 characters are random, next 4 character are year and month, and 9 types of extensions.

I am using this batch script to create these folders:-

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=C:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=C:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET name=%%~na
 SET ext=%%~xa
 SET name=!name:~0,8!\!name:~8,4!\!ext:~1!
 MD "!name!" 2>nul
 MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!name!\" >nul
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Now I would like to add a WINRAR command to archive just the extension folders created in step 3, I am using this command to create the archives.

```
C:\ ABCEFGHI\0703\PDF>WINRAR A PDF C:\ ABCEFGHI\0703\PDF
```

Is it possible to add this command to the script?

Comment: Have a look at rar.exe in your WinRAR folder

Comment: Well... puh. Uhm in answering your question: Yes it is possible... farther than that, i have no clue what you really want to know... could you please specify, what you have attempted and where you have failed? (or have you even failed? your solution seems pretty solid..)

Comment: No I have not tried. I am not sure. How to incorporate winrar with script. Especially when I have to rar a file that is not created as yet. The script needs to create folders first and then zip them? How do I do that? Can u pls assist with the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first you need to have rar.exe in a folder in %PATH%,

i'd suggest you put a link in your Windows\System32 folder like so:

```
mklink C:\Windows\System32\rar.exe "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe"
```

then you can get to work.

As you already suggested, first create the desired directory tree and then just add the required files to your archive like so:

```
rar.exe a %ARCHIVE_NAME% MainFolder\*.pdf
rar.exe a %ARCHIVE_NAME% MainFolder\FolderA\*
rar.exe a %ARCHIVE_NAME% MainFolder\FolderB\*
```

Whereas %ARCHIVE_NAME% is the file name of your *new* target archive (such as foo.rar)

This will every *.pdf file in 'MainFolder' and everything in 'FolderA' and 'FolderB'. The directory tree **will be preserved**.

Also, you may want to check whether %ARCHIVE_NAME% **already exists**, since rar will just add the specified files to an existing archive (possibly overriding them)

Hope this clarifies some things for you.

**Edit: doing this recursivly for unknown root directory**

```
set ARCHIVE_NAME=%CD%\pdf_archive.rar
for /r %CD% %%d in ('PDF') do (
    if exist "%%d" (
        echo Archiving files in: %%d
        rar a "%ARCHIVE_NAME% "%%d"\*
    )
)
```

Now this will go into **every** subdirectory recursivly (starting from your current directory)

Then iw will look for folders called 'PDF' and if they exist it will archive **every** file in that folder to %ARCHIVE_NAME%

Comment: Thanks issue is my main folder is unknown the first script will create these directories. I need the script to search in any destination folders for something called PDF and archive it.

Comment: On what level do these PDF folders exist? (Do you need recursion?)

Comment: So there is all the random 8 digit folder name, then a subfolder called 0705 (year and month), then the actual sub folder called PDF

Comment: Need more info on recursion I believe yes I do because winrar needs to work after the first script has created folders.

Comment: See the edit on my post. It provides a for loop that recurses to every sub directory...

Comment: @ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=C:\2BW00885" 
SET "destdir=C:\2BW00885" 
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ( 
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" ' 
 ) DO ( 
 SET name=%%~na 
 SET ext=%%~xa 
 SET name=!name:~0,8!\!name:~8,4!\!ext:~1! 
 MD "!name!" 2>nul 
 MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!name!\" >nul 
) 
GOTO :EOF 
set ARCHIVE_NAME=%CD%\CU_archive.rar 
for /r %CD% %%d in ('CU_') do ( 
    if exist "%%d" ( 
        echo Archiving files in: %%d 
        rar a "%ARCHIVE_NAME% "%%d"\* 
    ) 
)

Comment: Sorry please see attached

Comment: @ECHO OFF 
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
    SET "sourcedir=C:\2BW00885" 
    SET "destdir=C:\2BW00885" 
    FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ( 
      'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" ' 
     ) DO ( 
     SET name=%%~na 
     SET ext=%%~xa 
     SET name=!name:~0,8!\!name:~8,4!\!ext:~1! 
     MD "!name!" 2>nul 
     MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!name!\" >nul 
    ) 
    GOTO :EOF 
    set ARCHIVE_NAME=%CD%\CU_archive.rar 
    for /r %CD% %%d in ('CU_') do ( 
        if exist "%%d" ( 
            echo Archiving files in: %%d 
            rar a "%ARCHIVE_NAME% "%%d"\* 
        ) 
    )

Comment: Yes I realised that and I moved it to the end.